# Uneven line diagram plotting and change of date format

Tags: python, pandas

I have two strange issue from the pandas plot. Below is the sample data I am working on which is a data set of three pressure values. I just want to plot these values as line diagram with date as xaxis.

```
Date    D1  D2  D3
01/01/2017  1013    1013    1013
02/01/2017  1014    1013.5  1015
03/01/2017  1014    1014.5  1014
04/01/2017  1014    1014    1012.4
05/01/2017  1014    1013.5  1012
06/01/2017  1014    1014    1012
07/01/2017  1012    1013    1011.8
08/01/2017  1012    1012    1011.8
09/01/2017  1011    1011    1012
10/01/2017  1012    1012    1013.6
11/01/2017  1012    1013    1014
12/01/2017  1013    1013    1013
13/01/2017  1013    1013    1013
14/01/2017  1012    1012.5  1012
15/01/2017  1014.5  1012    1015
16/01/2017  1014    1014    1015.9
17/01/2017  1015    1015    1015.4
18/01/2017  1015    1014    1015.6
19/01/2017  1014    1014    1015
20/01/2017  1014    1013    1015.3
21/01/2017  1014    1014    1014
22/01/2017  1014    1013    1016
23/01/2017  1014    1013    1016
24/01/2017  1014    1013    1016
25/01/2017  1014    1014    1015
26/01/2017  1014    1014    1014.7
27/01/2017  1014    1013    1013.5
28/01/2017  1013    1012    1013.4
29/01/2017  1012    1013    1014
30/01/2017  1012    1014    1014.5
31/01/2017  1014    1013    1014
01/02/2017  1014    1014    1012
02/02/2017  1014    1013    1014
03/02/2017  1014    1016    1013
04/02/2017  1014    1014    1015
05/02/2017  1014    1013    1013
06/02/2017  1013    1013    1014
07/02/2017  1015    1014    1013
08/02/2017  1014    1014    1015
09/02/2017  1014    1013    1014
10/02/2017  1014    1013    1013
11/02/2017  1014    1013    1013
12/02/2017  1013    1014    1014
13/02/2017  1013    1014    1014
14/02/2017  1016    1015.5  1015.6
15/02/2017  1016    1015.5  1015
16/02/2017  1016    1015    1012
17/02/2017  1016    1016    1011.9
18/02/2017  1014    1016    1012.3
19/02/2017  1015    1013    1013.4
20/02/2017  1015    1016    1012.3
21/02/2017  1014    1015    1010.7
22/02/2017  1012    1013    1010.7
23/02/2017  1013    1013    1013.2
24/02/2017  1014    1013    1013.2
25/02/2017  1013    1013    1014
26/02/2017  1014    1014    1014.5
27/02/2017  1013    1013    1011.3
28/02/2017  1012    1013    1012.6
```

Here is the bare minimum sample code I have for plotting the above data

```
df = pd.read_csv(data_path, index_col=0, parse_dates=True)
df1 = df[['D1', 'D2', 'D3']]
plt1 = df1.plot(marker='o', figsize=(16, 9), title=title, grid=True)
```

and here is the strange plotting I got:-

[image]
You can see two strange issue from the plot:-

1. The plotting is squed at the begining and not even.
2. The date format which was in DD:MM:YYYY has changed to completely different.

Can some one guide me in solving above issues?

Comment: What happens if you get rid of `parse_dates` and, instead do the following as a separate operation: `df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.Date, "%d/%m/%Y")`?

Comment: It throws an error `'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Date'`

Comment: Switch `Date` for `index` sorry. That was what I had originally then edited it. So `df.index`

Comment: Able to extract the index but again received this error `AssertionError`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the parameter `dayfirst=True` for [**`pd.read_csv`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)

```
df = pd.read_csv(data_path, index_col=0, parse_dates=True, dayfirst=True)
df1 = df[['D1', 'D2', 'D3']]
plt1 = df1.plot(marker='o', figsize=(16, 9), title=title, grid=True)
```

[image]

Comment: So simple. I thought this is what my suggestion in the comments would have achieved (in a roundabout way) yet apparently it didn't...

Comment: I've had this in the past. `read_csv` seems a lot more flexible with datatype than building a DF from, say, a nested list. For example, `read_csv` will parse `"FALSE"` as `False` but not if I try from a list. Is there a simple way to recreate the csv reader flexibility outside of reading csvs? I'm missing something.

Comment: @roganjosh I've only come across very few things that `read_csv` can do that can't be done easily outside of it.  And unfortunately, those few things aren't coming to mind.  But if you run into an issue where you feel you'd like to solve by constructing a dataframe directly but only seem to be able to do it by importing an csv, please post a question.  I'm sure you'll get an answer.

Comment: Ok that's reassuring because I have several instances and thought I was missing something basic. Another example is that it would convert a numerical column to float for me automatically, regardless of a blank string present, but would throw errors if I tried to so the same with `astype()` when creating from nested list. I will prepare a question in the next few days.

Comment: I raised as a question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45753777/why-is-read-csv-so-much-more-permissive-when-inferring-dtype

Comment: @roganjosh: the behavior is very version-dependent, especially for something as actively-changing and with as many bugs as pandas. So you should specify the version number when commenting on its behavior.