# Can I access read_csv()'s dtype inference engine when creating a DataFrame from a nested list?

Tags: python, pandas, types, type-inference

This follows from a discussion with piRSquared [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45742526/4799172), where I found that `read_csv` seems to have its own type inference methods that appear to be broader in their ability to obtain the correct type. It also appears to be more fault-tolerant in the case of missing data, electing for `NaN` instead of throwing `ValueError` as its default behaviour.

There's a lot of cases where the inferred datatypes are perfectly acceptable for my work but this functionality doesn't seem to be exposed when instantiating a `DataFrame`, or anywhere else in the API that I can find, meaning that I have to manually deal with `dtypes` unnecessarily. This can be tedious if you have hundreds of columns. The closest I can find is [`convert_objects()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.convert_objects.html) but it doesn't handle the bools in this case. The alternative I could use is to dump to disk and read it back in, which is grossly inefficient.

The below example illustrates the default behaviour of `read_csv` vs. the default behaviour of the conventional methods for setting dtype (correct in V `0.20.3`). Is there a way to access the type inference of `read_csv` without dumping to disk? More generally, is there a reason why `read_csv` behaves like this?

Example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import csv

data = [['string_boolean', 'numeric', 'numeric_missing'], 
        ['FALSE', 23, 50], 
        ['TRUE', 19, 12], 
        ['FALSE', 4.8, '']]

with open('my_csv.csv', 'w') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    writer.writerows(data)

# Reading from CSV
df = pd.read_csv('my_csv.csv')
print(df.string_boolean.dtype) # Automatically converted to bool
print(df.numeric.dtype) # Float, as expected
print(df.numeric_missing.dtype) # Float, doesn't care about empty string

# Creating directly from list without supplying datatypes
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=data[0])
df2.string_boolean = df2.string_boolean.astype(bool) # Doesn't work - ValueError
df2.numeric_missing = df2.numeric_missing.astype(np.float64) # Doesn't work

# Creating but forcing dtype doesn't work
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=data[0], 
                   dtype=[bool, np.float64, np.float64])

# The working method
df4 = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=data[0])
df4.string_boolean.map({'TRUE': True, 'FALSE': False})
df4.numeric_missing = pd.to_numeric(df4.numeric_missing)
```

Comment: I assume your actual question is how to allow for flexible dtype determination when your input data is something else than a CSV file?

Comment: @Evert It's a bit of a mix; is there a way to get `read_csv` inference behaviour without the csv step, and also why is the default behaviour so different?

Comment: Note that `pdf.read_csv` accepts a `StringIO` object. Thus you can create a `StringIO` object out of your nested list and feed that into `pd.read_csv`. Not the prettiest work-around, but possibly nicer than what you use right now (as for your current solution, you may want to go with `tempfile`).

Comment: I would put that first half of your comment way more at the top of your question. Currently, your question is mainly about a design decision. Which is not going to help your issue. I initially read it as being only about a design decision, not an actual problem you had.

Comment: @Evert Rereading, I did wander off topic. I've removed design choice paragraph. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @evert seems like your method is the way forward at this point. Feel free to post as an answer so I can close this off. Thanks for your suggestion :)

Comment: This reads like several unclear questions in one. Are you curious why `pd.read_csv()` does inference better than `pd.DataFrame()` (because the former has a type-inference engine built in and the later doesn't)? Or you want a hack to access the former from the latter? (presumably write out as a string then read back with `StringIO`, possibly using chunking for large files)? Or you're discussing a change-request on pd.DataFrame(), which is kind of offtopic? Can you please edit it to be clear?

Comment: Also in your question everywhere you say *"Doesn't work"* please include what Error it causes, or whether just falls back to `object' type. Otherwise, interesting as this, I'm not seeing that you're asking a specific question.

Comment: @smci you've certainly followed the trail re: this question :) I would say that my desire was clear and on-topic; I want to access the specific dtype inference used by `read_csv` without dumping to disk. As a question, I have to make some qualification of why I want such behaviour and immediately I hit problems. I can't frame that desire without derailing myself on Pandas I/O; why should there be some specific system unique to CSV that isn't (that I know) be exposed in the API? Why should converting data to a string be better at inferring Booleans?

Comment: @smci my other comments weren't relevant, I reconsidered. Hopefully my edit addresses your comments (not just here but across multiple questions)

Comment: ok it's cleaner now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to use a `StringIO` object. The only difference is that it keeps all the data in memory, instead of writing to disk and reading back in.

Code is as follows (note: Python 3!):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import csv
from io import StringIO

data = [['string_boolean', 'numeric', 'numeric_missing'],
        ['FALSE', 23, 50],
        ['TRUE', 19, 12],
        ['FALSE', 4.8, '']]

with StringIO() as fobj:
    writer = csv.writer(fobj)
    writer.writerows(data)
    fobj.seek(0)
    df = pd.read_csv(fobj)

print(df.head(3))
print(df.string_boolean.dtype) # Automatically converted to bool
print(df.numeric.dtype) # Float, as expected
print(df.numeric_missing.dtype) # Float, doesn't care about empty string
```

The `with StringIO() as fobj` isn't really necessary: `fobj = String()` will work just as fine. And since the context manager will close the `StringIO()` object outside its scope, the `df = pd.read_csv(fobj)` has to be inside it.
Note also the `fobj.seek(0)`, which is another necessity, since your solution simply closes and reopens a file, which will automatically set the file pointer to the start of the file.

### A note on Python 2 vs Python 3

I actually tried to make the above code Python 2/3 compatible. That became a mess, because of the following: Python 2 has an `io` module, just like Python 3, whose `StringIO` class makes everything unicode (also in Python 2; in Python 3 it is, of course, the default).
That is great, except that the `csv` writer module in Python 2 is *not* unicode compatible.
Thus, the alternative is to use the (older) Python 2 `(c)StringIO` module, for example as follows:

```
try:
    from cStringIO import StringIO
except ModuleNotFoundError:  # Python 3
    from io import StringIO
```

and things will be plain text in Python 2, and unicode in Python 3.
Except that now, `cStringIO.StringIO` does not have a context manager, and the `with` statement will fail. As I mentioned, it is not really necessary, but I was keeping things as close as possible to your original code.
In other words, I could not find a nice way to stay close to the original code without ridiculous hacks.

I've also looked at avoiding the CSV writer completely, which leads to:

```
text = '\n'.join(','.join(str(item).strip("'") for item in items) 
                 for items in data)

with StringIO(text) as fobj:
    df = pd.read_csv(fobj)
```

which is perhaps neater (though a bit less clear), *and* Python 2/3 compatible. (I don't expect it to work for everything that the `csv` module can handle, but here it works fine.)

---

### Why can't `pd.DataFrame(...)` do the conversion?

Here, I can only speculate.

I would think the reasoning is that when the input are Python objects (dicts, lists), the input is known, and in hands of the programmer. Therefore, it is unlikely, perhaps even illogical, that that input would contain strings such as `'FALSE'` or `''`. Instead, it would normally contain the objects `False` and `np.nan` (or `math.nan`), since the programmer would already have taken care of the (string) translation.
Whereas for a file (CSV or other), the input can be anything: your colleague might send an Excel CSV file, or someone else sends you a Gnumeric CSV file. I don't know how standardised CSV files are, but you'd probably need some code to allow for exceptions, and overall for the conversion of the strings to Python (NumPy) format.

So in that sense, it is actually illogical to expect `pd.DAtaFrame(...)` to accept just anything: instead, it *should* accept something that is properly formatted.

You might argue for a convenience method that takes a list like yours, but a list is not a CSV file (which is just a bunch of characters, including newlines). Plus, I expect there is the option for `pd.read_csv` to read the files in chunks (perhaps even line by line), which becomes harder if you'd feed it a string with newlines instead (you can't really read that line by line, as you would have to split it on newlines and keep all the lines in memory. And you already have the full string in memory somewhere, instead of on disk. But I digress).

Besides, the `StringIO` trick is just a few lines to precisely perform this trick.