# pandas read_excel: nan values forcing others in the same column to be converted to float

Tags: python, excel, pandas, io, nan

Let's say I have the following Excel file to be read:

> [image]

**What I want** is a simple solution (preferrably one-line) that can read the excel so that the dates are converted to `str` (or at least `int`), and the blank values are to `nan` or `nat` or whatever can be detected by `pd.isnull`.

If I use `df = pd.read_excel(file_path)`, what I get is

```
df
Out[8]: 
              001002.XY  600123.AB  123456.YZ   555555.GO
ipo_date     20100203.0   20150605        NaN  20090501.0
delist_date         NaN   20170801        NaN         NaN
```

So pandas recognised blank cells as `NaN`, which is fine, but the pet peeve is that all the other values are forced to `float64`, even if they are intended to be just `str` or `int`s. (**edit**: it seems that if a column, e.g. the column `[1]`, has no `nan`s, then the other values won't be forced to `float`. However, in my case most columns have `delist_date` blank, since most stocks have an ipo date but are not delisted yet.)

For what I know though, I tried the `dtype=str` keyword arg, and it gives me

```
df
Out[10]: 
            001002.XY 600123.AB 123456.YZ 555555.GO
ipo_date     20100203  20150605       nan  20090501
delist_date       nan  20170801       nan       nan
```

Looks good? True, the dates are now `str`, but one thing ridiculous is that the `nan`s now become literal strings! E.g.

```
df.iloc[1, 0]
Out[12]: 
'nan'
```

which would make me have to add something weird like `df.replace` later on.

I didn't try the `converters` because it would require specifying datatype column by column, and the actual excel file I'm working with is a very long spreadsheet (3k columns approx). I don't want to transpose the spreadsheet in excel itself either.

Could anybody help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've found similar unexpected behaviour. I don't know if the excellent answer from Evert to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45814200/4799172) gives any insight.

Comment: @roganjosh thanks Im gonna check it out.

Comment: It definitely is a tangent but I do find the datatype conversion odd (from csv in my case) so perhaps it gives you another angle.

Comment: Can you try dtype=object ?

Comment: @amanbirs yes it works! It reads all dates as ints while leaving blanks as nan.

Comment: @roganjosh please see the comment by amanbirs. Setting `dtype=object` works in my case anyway even though I don't understand the deep reasons behind it. Hopefully it can work in your case too.

Comment: Note that setting dtype as object means you can't vectorize any operations. It kinda defeats the purpose of pandas.

Comment: @roganjosh oh... didn't try it. Perhaps you're right.

Comment: Implicit conversion to a particular type was my question and I thought it was related to yours. If you cast as `object` then you have no hope of vectorized calculations. But, it could be a step to getting your input into the right format to vectorize after that.

Comment: @roganjosh actually after setting dtype=object it will convert dates to ints and blanks to NaN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use dtype=object as the parameter.

Great explanation here: [pandas distinction between str and object types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34881079/pandas-distinction-between-str-and-object-types)