# How is dtype inference done for each column in pandas read_csv?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, type-inference, pandas-datareader

Im curious on how the dtype is decided for each column while reading from a csv file into a dataframe in pandas.

For example when reading a csv file, though the values are int they can get a dtype of 'object' instead of 'int', and checking the type of the column value gives `(class str)`

Is there a way to check the type before actually creating the dataframe in `read_csv` pandas method?

Comment: I had a very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45753777/4799172). It doesn't properly answer your question but I've found the parsing behaviour odd/inconsistent and Evert made a great effort in getting similar behaviour from csv as other inputs.

Comment: @roganjosh I tried using the StringIO object as suggested , in reading the csv file , but no luck , the column still is parsed as a string

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't suggesting that it would solve the issue (indeed, I was trying to _replicate_ read_csv behaviour in that question). Just that read_csv seems to have some different rules on how inputs are parsed to type (actually, read_csv was happy to implicitly convert to a numerical type for me, even if there were nan values in a column, so not sure why you're getting object type).

Comment: @roganjosh I checked through the csv file , becoz of a "?" in the column value the entire column was converted to object dtype.

Is there a precedence over the dtypes assignment in a dataframe?

Comment: I was interested in this too. I went to the source code. but got lost in teh codez. If you want to check the source code - you can always search for `read_csv` and its components

Comment: *"How is dtype inferred?"* as per the current version of the source: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/io/parsers.py ; see also their doc. Unless you have a specific question, noone's going to write an essay answer on ~5+K lines of complex and actively-changing code.

Comment: *"Is there a way to check the type before actually creating the dataframe in read_csv pandas method?"* I think you mean you want to access the type inference engine, specifically get the list of columns and inferred dtypes, rather than the output dataframe? If so that's a duplicate of @roganjosh's [Can I access dtype inference of read_csv() when creating a DataFrame from a nested list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45753777/can-i-access-dtype-inference-of-read-csv-when-creating-a-dataframe-from-a-nest), please close this

Comment: Other than that, if you want to get a feel for the code in action, run it under the debugger on some sample input.

Comment: It might help if you gave specific example e.g. *"uncompressed CSV file, no quoting, escaping or funky encoding, with int row-index, one header row, and mixed int, string, boolean and datetime columns"*. Show us ten rows of such a file..