# Specify the data type of each column in read_csv from each column of an HTTP header

Tags: python, pandas, types, http-headers, type-inference

```
project_id = request.data['project']
list_fields = request.POST.getlist('headers')
type_fields = request.POST.getlist('type')

dataframe = pandas.read_csv(file_path, header=0)
                for field in list_fields:
                    for tipo in type_fields:
                        dataframe[field] = dataframe[field].astype(type)
```

how can I assign each type of data to a column according to the past in the request?

Comment: How does `file_path` relate to `list_fields`? On the front-end, the user specifies the type for each field, and the file is read independently? If so, you could probably use `zip` on `list_fields` and `type_field` and iterate that list.

Comment: In other words, the types could be specified when the df is created but your snippet doesn't cover the whole picture.

Comment: list_fields takes the csv file headers

Comment: Ok, think I understand the setup. Not home for a little while yet to test, will give my interpretation when I get back.

Comment: This is a duplicate. Just directly use the `pd.read_csv` parameter [`dtype` which allows a dict mapping <column_name> to <dtype>](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html). If the conversion is error-prone or requires any conversion (e.g. dates, times, etc.), then use parameter `converters`. If you need to write a custom converter function(s) then do that. If you encountered a specific coding issue with any of that then post it.

Comment: If you want to iterate over the two lists in parallel, do `for ffield, ftype in zip(list_fields, type_fields):` (assuming of course they have the same length). But like I said doing type coercion/inference after `read_csv()` rather than at `read_csv()` time will always be more error-prone and manual. So better to do it inside `read_csv()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `from_csv()`, pandas will do an awful lot of type inference. In fact, more so than other methods such as [`convert_objects`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.convert_objects.html). I asked a question about it [`here`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45753777/accessing-dtype-parsing-behaviour-of-read-csv-when-creating-a-dataframe-from-a-n), which is somewhat related.

I'm presuming that the front-end user has to specify the dtype of every column. In which case, it's a simple case of:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6], 'c': [7, 8, 9]}, 
                   dtype=int)

list_fields = ['a', 'b', 'c']
list_types = [str, int, np.float64]

for field, dtype in zip(list_fields, list_types):
    df[field] = df[field].astype(dtype)

print(df.dtypes)
```

If the users don't have to specify the dtype of all of the fields then, on further thought, I think that would be a different topic entirely on how you filter/process user input.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a list from the front with all the columns that you want to define, than pass another list with all the types that you want for the columns. After that you can cast those loops.

```
to_define_list_fields = request.POST.getlist('define')

type_list_fields = request.POST.getlist('types')                  

for dfield in to_define_list_fields:

   for type in type_list_fields:

       dataframe[dfield] = dataframe[dfield].astype(type)
```

Comment: It makes no sense to have a nested loop here. 1 column, 1 type. Why have 2 `for` loops?

Comment: @roganjosh: presumably `for dfield, dtype in zip(list_fields, type_fields):`