# Pandas specify read_csv() type inference order of precedence or list

Tags: python, pandas

The default behavior for `pandas.read_csv()` (as far as I can tell) is to first try to interpret column data as `int`, and only if that fails does it try to interpret as `float`.

I want to modify this behavior to prefer `float` or simply exclude `int`, but it doesn't seem like I can get there with `read_csv`'s options. It appears the only way to modify type handling is thorough the `dtypes` parameter, but that is only useful for specifying either (1) a single type for all columns or (2) a mapping of column names to dtypes.

Is there a way to get `read_csv` to behave in either of the two ways described? To handle this currently, I am iterating over all numeric columns after calling `read_csv` and then coercing them explicitly with `.astype(np.float)`, an unnecessary extra step (in thoery!).

Comment: I had the [reverse question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45753777/can-i-access-read-csvs-dtype-inference-engine-when-creating-a-dataframe-from) but never quite understood how it works :/

Comment: There is no clean way of doing that as far as I can tell. The only hack I can think of is to insert a row of nulls at the top, since int columns cannot have nulls.