# Pandas read_xml reading "N/A" as NaN

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, xml, dataframe

I am reading xml file using "read_xml " function available in the pandas.

xml-file

`<resources>`
`<string name="label_generate_transfer_code">Generate Transfer Code</string>`
`<string name="label_select_all">Select All</string>`
`<string name="label_sequence_number">Sequence Number: %1$s</string>`
`<string name="label_serial_number">Serial Number: %1$s</string>`
`<string name="label_model">Model: %1$s</string>`
`<string name="transfer_confirmation_feature_item">• %1$s</string>`
`<string name="label_current">(Current)</string>`
`<string name="label_primary_display">Primary Display</string>`
`<string name="label_secondary_display">Secondary Display</string>`
`<string name="label_pcm">PCM</string>`
`<string name="label_receiver">Receiver</string>`
**`<string name="label_not_available">N/A</string>`**
`<string name="label_menu">Menu</string>`
`<string name="label_activations">Activations</string>`
`<string name="label_activations_title">Activation Input Method</string>`
`</resources>`

This is what I am doing to read xml file.

`local_xml_frame = pd.read_xml(xml_file_path,xpath=".//string")`

While reading xml file, pandas is converting "N/A" string value to NaN".

[image]

I went through official document which states that "Data type for data or columns. E.g. {‘a’: np.float64, ‘b’: np.int32, ‘c’: ‘Int64’} "**Use str or object together with suitable na_values settings to preserve and not interpret dtype**". If converters are specified, they will be applied INSTEAD of dtype conversion."

I unable to comprehend how to use highlighted information to avoid conversion of "N/A" to NaN.

Could someone provide me exact solution to this problem?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel. Can you explain why you closed the question, please? I don't understand the dupe. `pd.read_csv` is not `pd.read_xml`. And there is no option `keep_default_na` in `pd.read_xml`.

Answer (score 2):

Another workaround is to parse manually the xml file then convert it as csv then read again with `pd.read_csv` to let Pandas infer the data type:

```
from lxml import etree
from io import StringIO

data = []
root = etree.parse(local_xml_path)
for elmt in root.findall('.//string'):
    d = elmt.attrib
    d.update({elmt.tag: elmt.text})
    data.append(d)
buf = StringIO(pd.DataFrame(data).to_csv(index=False))
df = pd.read_csv(buf, keep_default_na=False)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
                                  name                   string
0         label_generate_transfer_code   Generate Transfer Code
1                     label_select_all               Select All
2                label_sequence_number    Sequence Number: %1$s
3                  label_serial_number      Serial Number: %1$s
4                          label_model              Model: %1$s
5   transfer_confirmation_feature_item                   • %1$s
6                        label_current                (Current)
7                label_primary_display          Primary Display
8              label_secondary_display        Secondary Display
9                            label_pcm                      PCM
10                      label_receiver                 Receiver
11                 label_not_available                      N/A
12                          label_menu                     Menu
13                   label_activations              Activations
14             label_activations_title  Activation Input Method
```

---

There are no parameters `na_values`, `keep_default_na` or `na_filter` like for `pd.read_csv` function. However in the documentation of `pd.read_xml`, we can read for `dtype` parameter:

> **dtype** Type name or dict of column -> type, optional
>
> Data type for data or columns. E.g. {‘a’: np.float64, ‘b’: np.int32, ‘c’: ‘Int64’} Use str or object together with suitable **na_values** settings to preserve and not interpret dtype. If converters are specified, they will be applied INSTEAD of dtype conversion.

But when you try something like `pd.read_xml(..., dtype=str, na_values=[])`, Pandas raises a `TypeError: read_xml() got an unexpected keyword argument 'na_values'` exception. So the documentation is not consistent with [the code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/2e218d10984e9919f0296931d92ea851c6a6faf5/pandas/io/xml.py#L838-L1104).

A possible workaround:

```
cols = local_xml_frame.select_dtypes(object).columns
local_xml_frame[cols] = local_xml_frame[cols].fillna('N/A')
```

Comment: That isn't a workaround, though. You've allowed it to parse the string incorrectly and then just mopped up with `fillna()`. That's indiscriminate - how do you know that all null values were `"N/A"` at the start?

Comment: I don't know but I guess for a structured document there is only one way to encode null values... but probably I'm wrong.

Comment: FWIW I had a pop at this. It's the result of a chat convo, with the most-relevant pieces starting [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/56204250#56204250). The parser doesn't seem consistent

Comment: @roganjosh. I propose another workaround from scratch. What do you think about that?

Comment: "pandas is even more borked than I thought" :P

Comment: I had my [own question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45753777/can-i-access-read-csvs-dtype-inference-engine-when-creating-a-dataframe-from) on dtype inference. It's... pretty chaotic.

Comment: @Corralien i got it ,it seems like pandas documentation issue ,will switch to manual parsing....this seems to be possible solution until we don't get fix from pandas